How can I change IDA global data type?
I am new to IDA and my IDA's version is 7.7.
I think it's quite difficult to read the data, especially for some struct with address:
IDA .data
It's very easy to know the next node is 0x0804c110 in gdb:
gdb
How can I fix this problem?
I tried to set Options-Regular-String and Options-Set Data Type but it still couldn't work as well as gdb.

I dont know why I can't show picture directly, sorry for inconvenience :(

I suggest you to press 'D' key where you want to change the data type. It cycles through db, dd and dw. Also you can define an array by pressing the numpad '*'.

IDA Pro has pretty good type system you could use. You could define each member of your struct as a proper data type like @StasSimonov suggested (and then mark your next field as an offset so that IDA shows it as such, and applies forward and back-references for your convenience.
However besides elemental data types, IDA also supports composite data types i.e. structs (see https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/structs/). So the best course of action would be to define your Node struct, mark next as offset and maybe type it as Node*. You could then mark your static data as proper structure type using Alt-Q shortcut. That would give you the best possible output, including named fields in the disassembly.
